# Storing counter inside cassandra collection

Tags: cassandra

I want to store aggregation data from my sensor, here's my schema plan for cassandra table

**UPDATED**

```
CREATE TABLE every_second_aggregate_signature(
    device_id text,
    year int,
    month int,
    day int,
    hour int,
    minute int,
    second int,
    signature map<text,counter>,
    PRIMARY KEY ((device_id, year, month, day, hour, minute, second))
)WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (year DESC, month DESC, day DESC, hour DESC, minute DESC, second DESC);
```

The signature data is in form of increment value and dynamic value, ex.

```
ts1 - {"4123sad" : 80, "djas10" : 99}
ts2 - {"4123sad" : 83, "djas10" : 103}
ts3 - {"4123sad" : 87, "djas10" : 198, "asfac9" : 281}
ts4 - {"4123sad" : 89, "djas10" : 201, "asfac9" : 540, "asd81" : 12}
```

The problem is I knew that cassandra didn't support counter inside the collection. Are there any alternative approach or solution to this problem ? Thanks for your help

Comment: whats your primary and clustering keys?

Comment: @ChrisLohfink updated the question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only alternative approach here is to move the "key" of the map into primary key of the table. Right now you're trying to model like this (as I understood):

```
create table counters (
  ts timestamp primary key,
  counters map<text, counter>
);
```

Then you'll need to change it to following:

```
create table counters (
  ts timestamp,
  key text,
  counter counter,
  primary key (ts, key)
);
```

And to select all values that should go into map, you simply do

```
select ts, key, counter from counters where ts = 'some value';
```

it will return you every pair of key/counter for given `ts` in the separate rows, so you'll need to have a code that merge them into map...

Comment: It is possible actually, but does that mean I have to store each key as one row ?
It's my first time to work with cassandra, does this type of model didn't make the workload high ?

Comment: Yes, you need to store every key as separate row. It's the limitation of the `counter` type - you can't have counter & non-counter values inside the same table - all non-counter values should be in the primary key.

Comment: Also, if you're going to count something where you need a precision, then the counter type isn't what you need - they are approximate, and could diverge.

Comment: actually I'm not planning on use cassandra aggregate function. I will aggregate the metric and count it inside apache spark. That way spark will update the table each new event is streamed. So, precision is not my #1 concern, performance is.

Comment: I knew I shouldn't ask for more in comment, but what is another approach rather than counter that has more precision ?

Comment: If you're anyway using Spark for data aggregations, I recommend to keep every measurement as a separate row, aggregate on it, and then delete data. For such use case, the TWCS with TTL on data will be the good choice...